# Mapping between UK SIC and US NAICS industry sector classification; other countries?

Tags: classification, industry

I am analyzing UK government company registry ([CompaniesHouse](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/companies-house)) data. In UK you have SIC (Standard Industrial Classification) codes that help define what industry sector a company operates in. I am aware of North American Industry Classification System (NAICS) that seems to operate similarly. Is there any mapping between the two? What do other countries do?

Comment: us uses SIC too, https://www.osha.gov/pls/imis/sicsearch.html. what exactly is CompaniesHouse? url? would like to help word this question better.

Comment: I don't think there is a mapping between the classifications, unfortunately.

Comment: @famargar, what about these links: http://lmsresources.labormarketinfo.com/library/ep/resources/naics02tosic87.xls, http://www.air-worldwide.com/Documentation/Verisk-Cyber-Exposure-Data-Standard-Preparer%27s-Guide/mapping_iso_and_naics_sic_codes.htm, https://www.bls.gov/ppi/ppisicnaics03.htm, https://www.bea.gov/faq/index.cfm?faq_id=22, https://www.naics.com/naics-to-sic-crosswalk-search-results ?

Comment: As for other countries, there exists the so-called [ОКВЭД](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) in Russia.

Comment: @StanislavKralin interesting find. Do you happen to know of more recent file though?

Also, I think now Europe has moved to NACE, at least Belgium is using both the '03 and '08 editions. Judging to the file header "NAICS 02", I guess in 2003 NACE replaced NAICS.

Comment: And who uses UNSPSC codes? And is there any mapping between SIC and UNSPSC?

Comment: @marfi, I just googled it. Unfortunately, the only thing I understand is that SIC and NAICS are somethng like Russian ОКВЭД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any mapping between the two?

There exist miscellaneous services, e. g. [this one](https://siccode.com/en/naicscode/list/conversion).
However, I guess you are looking for a whole dataset, according to the scope of this site.

On [this page](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/concordances.html), I have found the following links:

- [2002 NAICS to 1987 SIC](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/2002_NAICS_to_1987_SIC.xls)
- [1987 SIC to 2002 NAICS](https://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/concordances/1987_SIC_to_2002_NAICS.xls)

The page also contains mappings between different versions of NAICS. Thus, one could construct mappings between SIC 1987 and recent versions of NAICS.

See also:

- [SIC Publication Structure and Comparable NAICS Indexes 
  in the Producer Price Index](https://www.bls.gov/ppi/ppisic-naics.pdf)
- [Is there a table that lists all the concordance codes (SIC, I-O, and NAICS)?](https://www.bea.gov/faq/index.cfm?faq_id=22)
- [NAICS to SIC Crosswalk](https://www.naics.com/naics-to-sic-crosswalk-search-results/) (press *View Crosswalk*)

> What do other countries do?

- [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_classification) contains list of industry classifications (11 items).
- [This Wikidata query](https://query.wikidata.org/#select%20%3Fsystem%20%3FsystemLabel%20where%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fsystem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ2976602%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2C%20de%2C%20ru%22%20.%20%7D%0A%7D) returns instances of `wd:Q2976602` (22 items).