# Concordance between ISIC Rev 2 and either SIC industries or NAICS industries

Tags: industry

I have a big dataset, with variables at the industry level. This dataset is presently at either the NAICS 1997 classification, or the SIC 1987 classification. I want to merge this dataset with an existing dataset which contains industry level data at the 3 digit ISIC Rev 2 level. The former (either NAICS or SIC) contain 400+ distinct sectors, whereas the ISIC contains only 28. As such, there should be a many to one mapping from either of the former to the ISIC Rev 2. I am unable to find concordance tables between either the NAICS or SIC to the ISIC Rev 2 (specifically 3 digit) classification.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12381/16193?

Comment: Thanks for your response- but this provides a link to a conversion from either NAICS to SIC or vice versa. I am looking for NAICS/SIC to 3 digit ISIC Rev 2

Comment: Possibly you could combine sone of these correspondences: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/ramon/relations/index.cfm?TargetUrl=LST_REL&StrLanguageCode=EN&IntCurrentPage=1 (14 pages)